# Woocommerce, email trouble, action to change the status of the order

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

in functions.php

```
function my_status_pending($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status("on-hold");
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'my_status_pending',  20  );
```

With this code, all email notifications of this order there is no list of custom goods, only the total amount. If you manually change the status of the order and send a letter from the admin list of goods becomes visible. Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Please use english, This is international website.